# How to fix router Wi-Fi random down-time?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

At home we have a `Sitecom Wireless Gigabit Router N300`. When it's working, it's great, but every now and then (seemingly randomly) the wireless connection will drop. The wireless network is still visible in Windows 8 / Ubuntu, but clients are unable to connect. Wired connections still work though.

Quite annoyingly, the router only keeps log messages for a short time period (30 min - 1 h), so I don't currently have the log file of the last time the wireless went down. I do recall there was a lot of:

```
Jul 18 16:33:50 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:33:49 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:33:47 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:33:45 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:33:32 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:32:58 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:32:42 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:32:32 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:32:12 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
Jul 18 16:32:08 [SYSTEM]: DHCP Server, Sending ACK of 192.168.0.108
```

and at a random moment

```
Jul 18 16:22:01 [SYSTEM]: UPnP, Start
Jul 18 16:22:58 [SYSTEM]: UPnP, Stopping
```

So perhaps this points to an issue with the UPnP module?

I googled around but could not find any relevant info for this router. To be honest I don't have a lot of knowledge regarding routers, so if you need more info, please let me know! (though I cannot provide new logs until the router decides to drop the Wi-Fi again...)

Update:
The Wi-Fi is down right now. Log file: http://pastebin.com/khctkWB1 . It went down around 17:40.

Comment: Are you running the latest firmware version on your router?

Comment: Do all of your devices support 802.11n?

Comment: Are all of your devices capable of connecting to the 5GHz band?

Comment: @MHrappstead: I think it is running the latest firmware, because it is set to automatically update to the latest version. Current version is 1.1, could not find details on firmware versions on sitecom's site... Regarding the 5GHz band: how could I find this out? The router says in the webinterface it is broadcasting at 2.4GHz

With regards to supporting 802.11n? I'm not sure if all devices do, but the network should be b/g/n combined...

Comment: Can you provide the product number or model number of the router? N300 refers to a large number of products Sitecom sells.

Comment: How often does the wireless network drop and for how long?

Comment: What device is using the 192.168.0.108 IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that the web interface says the router is broadcasting at 2.4GHz I assume it doesn't support 5GHz. The 2.4GHz band is more susceptible to interference then the 5GHz band because of the total number of devices (laptops, microwaves, etc) and technologies (bluetooth, etc) that use this band and the limited number of usable channels. I would do a scan to find out what channels the routers near you are using and try and pick a channel (1, 6, or 11) with the least use.

If all of your devices support the 5GHz band I would recommend you borrow a router that broadcasts at 5GHz and disable the 2.4GHz radio if the router supports both bands. Let it run for a while and see if it fixes the problem. If it works buy a router that supports the 5GHz band. I realize that buying a new router doesn't prove that the problem was caused by interference but at least we know it fixes the problem and wireless problems can be extremely difficult to troubleshoot. You can see if your devices support 5GHz by looking their specs up online.

As a side note if you are located outside of North America some of this information may be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have a look at what channels are in use and changing the channel. The wireless router only supports the 2.4GHz band, not 5GHz. To be honest I don't think much 5GHz compatible devices are being sold here (the Netherlands), though I may be mistaken.

Comment: So I had a look using my smartphone, it seems there was a lot of overlap with neighbouring access points. I changed the broadcasting channel, let's see if it helps.

Comment: Have not encountered the issue since changing the channel, so I think that did the trick! (though it could also have been turning off the UPnP)

Answer (score 2):

Turn the UPnP services in your router OFF.  UPnP is a service that allows devices internal to your LAN to configure the router without your interaction.  It isn't necessary, only convenient.  It is also a security risk.

Also if you are getting lots of traffic from that single IP address and you have multiple devices hooked up, try and run a malware scan on the device.  An infected system could try to use UPnP to allow itself to configure your router and let more malware in or else help the malware in some way.  I don't see why your DHCP server is sending out so many ACK packets like that.

Comment: I have turned off UPnP, interested to see if the problem persists. Regarding that IP: it was of my own computer, on which I re-installed windows just yesterday, so I wouldn't suspect it to have any malware. Will run a scan anyways.

Comment: I followed your advice, as well as MHrappstead's and have not encountered any issues since. Because I did so more or less at the same time, I'm not sure which of the two fixed my problem, but I think changing the channel did the trick, thus I marked that answer as the solution.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure how to fix it, but if all else fails, you can just buy a **Wireless Access Point (WAP)** seeing as the wired connections still work.

Comment: I don't understand entirely what you mean by "you can just by a WAP", could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: A WAP is a Wireless Access Point. From Wikipedia: "In computer networking, a wireless Access Point (AP) is a device that allows wireless devices to connect to a wired network using Wi-Fi, or related standards. The AP usually connects to a router (via a wired network) as a standalone device, but it can also be an integral component of the router itself."

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of WAP. So are you suggesting I should *buy* a separate wireless access-point? (In that case there is typo in your answer which makes it hard to uderstand.)

Comment: That is correct. They aren't too expensive and will save you a lot of effort troubleshooting.

Comment: I highly recommend you try the simple things first before throwing money at the problem.

Comment: Based on the symptoms I am guessing there is a small hardware defect.

Comment: @VirtualDXS - Once you fix the spelling mistakes that **might** happen. But I will be honest its a single sentence, its not really an answer, buying another access point really isn't helpful to other people nor how to solve the problem.

Comment: To be honest your answer doesn't really help, it just boils down to "If all else fails, buy a new device", which could be a 'solution' for any hardware related issue...